# XCode: access Segmented Control on TableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a TableView with 2 columns. Second column contains SegmentedControl button with two segments. What I would like to do is to modify the "enabled" property of the button for each row before the table is first displayed. I've searched and failed to find the right solution. How do I get access to SegmentedControl for each row?

Answer (score 0):

Use [tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforTableColumn%3arow%3a) delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[NSSegmentedCell class]])
    {
        if( 1) // add your condition
        {
            [(NSSegmentedCell*)cell setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that as it seems like the correct choice. However this method is not called when I switch to the view containing my TableView. The TableView's delegate is also set up properly.

Comment: Call reload data  when you switch to the view containing TableView

Comment: Still doesn't work. I found some other post saying that this method is not called with view based TableView. I managed to do this by creating segmented control in my code. So it does the job.